# issue fgetc() c using while loop

Tags: c, file, parsing, loops, fgetc

I got a big problem using fgetc() and i can't figure it out... I try to parse a text file, everything compile but at the execution I got an infinite loop or a segfault (Code::blocks), my text file is like that: {"USD_EUR": "0.8631364", "EUR_USD": "1.3964719"} with 16 rates change. I try to put all my float in rate[16]...

```
FILE* file = NULL;
file = fopen(myFile, "r+");
int value,i;
float rate[16];
char* str = "";
if (file != NULL)
{
    do
    {
        value = fgetc(file);
        printf("%c \n",value);
        while(value > 48 && value < 57)
        {
            value = fgetc(file);
            strcat(str, value);
            //printf("%s \n", str);
        }
        rate[i] = atof(str);
        i++;
        str = "";
    }while(value != 125); // 125 = }
```

Comment: Check the status of the file after the fopen function, please change the `valeur` to `value` as a variable and close the braces properly. And `=!` it is wrong the correct way is `!=`.

Comment: this does not compile, the first problem is valeur is not used.  The second problem is value is not defined.  The third problem is the line while( value =! EOF); is not correct, as it performs an assignment rather than a comparison.

Comment: @user3629249 ,OP showed the problematic part of his code and not the whole thing. Also,if OP can run the program,he/she must've compiled it.

Comment: OT: `(value < 48 && value > 57)` this will never be true.

Comment: Learn using a debugger to trace your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`while(value =! EOF);` should be `while(value != EOF);`

It's a big difference. First case is an assignment to the variable value, second case looks if value is not equal to EOF.

`EOF` is a macro and usually have the value `-1`, that means that `!EOF` becomes 0. Since you have a `do{} while()` it will run once but not more since condition is false.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't understand why this kind of mistakes pass the compilator...

Comment: @mel If you use `gcc` add you can use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, first enables many warnings, next some more and last one treats warnings as errors, meaning you get compile time errors.

Answer (score 3):

`while(value =! EOF)` is not same as `while(value != EOF)`

What you need is the latter `while(value != EOF)`

Answer (score 2):

in the while loop you are assigning the value to the variable value.

```
     `while(value =! EOF);`
```

The value of EOF is -1.(i.e) End of file. if it is !-1, then it will take as 0.
As it is a do while only once the loop will be executed, next time the condition will be false. So it gets only one character.
You can use

```
`while(value != EOF);`
```

which means not equal to EOF. Then the condition will be true and the loop will be executed till the condition becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of value is incorrect and make that correct.

`int value;`

While `( value != EOF )` is comparing the value to EOF. Here EOF is a macro having the
value as -1. Comparing the value with that.  You can see that using cc -E while compiling.

`(value =!EOF)` means that  `value =! (-1)` So `!(-1)` comes zero. That will assign to the variable value. So in condition zero is false.  So it come out from the loop. And you can check the value of variable value by printing that variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
The following code does the job of reading/echoing a input file
char by char.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *theFile = "input.txt";

int main()
{
    FILE* file = NULL;
    int value;

    if( NULL == ( file = fopen(theFile, "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( EOF != (value = fgetc(file) ) )
    {
        printf("%c \n",value);
    } // end while

    return(0);
} // end function: main
```